# Angular ui-router, save state by url/url variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Have an interesting problem I'm trying to see if I can solve with angulars ui router plugin. What I am trying to do is save a view state by means of a customized url.

I have set up a very basic example to see if this is possible then I would like to abstract upon this if it works!

So I very simply have a

```
$scope.test = false;
```

and then on the page there is an ng-click that toggles this test variable between true and false. So what I am trying to see if I can save that state and pass it in - so say if i change it to true, I would like to be able to save a URL and then go to that, when i come to that, this variable would then be changed to true (instead of it's default false in the controller)

So I was thinking I could try something like

```
url: "test/{form_id}"
```

(I'm assuming this is how this works), however I might want to pass more than just an id. BEST case scenario is I could pass an object entirely via url (or rather reference to one, I know passing an object sounds silly), but otherwise I'm assuming on either end I would have to set up a way to make the string for the id and a way to interpret it. If i could fashion it to be polymorphic that would be fantastic, however my first steps are trying to be able to do it on a low level.

So my thinking is - every time you click to change it sets a variable which can then be set on the url. If the url is given to someone who is logged into this app and goes to that view, the controller would know from the url that it needed to change the $scope.test = true on load. I'm wondering if it's possible to conquer this with angular-ui-router, and if so if someone would be willing to provide some guidance I would be most appreciative. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really pass a reference since you are talking about 2 different instances of the app.  But you could JSON encode your object, urlencode that and pass it on the URL.  If that is too big it will not work in all browsers though.  It would also be "better" in many cases to have a more semantic URL i.e. instead of passing a big old blob, use meaningful parameters and pass those.

The documentation for $routeParams is at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: Thank you! And to your point - i agree that I want to make the url as small as possible (but also send as much info as I can). I Think worst case scenario, in this app I would have to pass 10-15 parameters in the url about the view in play, but it would be cool to let it handle as many as it wanted in some way.